# Javascript not loading in the webview for android

Tags: android, mobile-webkit

I am trying to write an hybrid app for android. In this app I am trying to load jquery and bunch of other frameworks. All the javascripts are located in the assets folder. Now the problem is that when I try to load any javascript I dont see any exception, but the javascript does not load.

If I give the path of an invalid file or scheme, I immediately see a console message and log

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/underscore.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/backbone.js" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/app.js" />

</head>
<body>

    page loaded...

    <script>
        console.log('-----loading-----');
```

I never see page loaded or ---loading---

But if i remove js includes i see the script being executed. What could be going wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some.js"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="some2.js"/>
</head>
<body>

    page loaded...

    <script>
        console.log('-----loading-----');
</script>

</body>
```

where some.js
    console.log("!");

and some2.js
    console.log("2");

I only see ! never 2

Comment: The files do exist at the correct location. I have checked that

Comment: I had an issue with loading external scripts in a html5 doc yesterday. Been a long time since I was doing any web dev. My solution was to drop the type="..." attribute, I read 'somewhere' it's not needed anymore. Can't find where though. Anyway, might be worth a quick shot.

Comment: Did you put setJavaScriptEnabled(true) for your webview object?

Comment: @Kameswari javascript is enabled

Comment: If i pass any javascript using loadURL it works fine, its just the sourced js which have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Almost anything could be wrong with one of the javascript files. Take them out one by one to figure out which one is causing the problem, then debug the script. Something is undefined where it shouldn't be, There is a missing bracket or parenthesis, etc.

Comment: The javascript files are standard jquery files. I did a simple experiment, made js files, and added console.log("1"); and console.log("2"); in them. I then include these files in index.html but i only see 1 never see 2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the html. I source the above html to HTML5 validator. It suggested script cannot be a self contained tag.

I replaced  with

And it all started working. Gosh, such a huge waste of time at my end. Thanks anyways for all those who helped.